# CSS: How to override a class style with an enclosing div

Tags: html, css

I have a P element with style which I can't change.
I want to enclose it with a DIV to enforce a new font-size.
Why does the inner P ignore the div font-size?

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .para1 { font-size:small; }
    </style>
</head>

<div style="font-size:300% !important">
    <p class="para1">I must have been asleep, for certainly if I had been fully awake I must have noticed the approach to such a remarkable place. In the gloom the courtyard looked of considerable size, and as several dark ways led from it under great round arches it perhaps seemed bigger than it really is. I have not yet been able to see it by daylight.</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe test my answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a class to the wrapping div, like I did here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Zvrg/

HTML:

```
<div class="out_of_para1">
    <p class="para1">
```

CSS:

```
.out_of_para1 p {font-size: 300%;}
```

EDIT: based on last comment from OP

Answer (score 1):

I know you cant change the class but why cant you do this.

```
<div style="font-size:300% !important">
<p>I must have been asleep</p>
</div>
```

and not associate your "p" with any class??

Comment: I can't. I receive the p element and I enclose it with my div.

Answer (score 0):

Styles are only inherited if the value of the property is `inherit`. On the paragraph, the value of the property is `small`. Thus the font size of the *div* is `300%` but the font size of the paragraph is `small`.

You have to explicitly set the font size on the paragraph element.

You could do this with a descendent selector in the stylesheet:

```
div .para1 {
    font-size: 300%;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't know the paragraph class name. It can be different every time.

Comment: If he has another para1 and he doesn't want it to change, your solution will probably be faulty...

Comment: @EliGanem — Then use a type selector (`p`) instead of a class selector.

Comment: @Ivozor — Obviously the CSS will have to be tailored to the context the code appears in.